# Unable to create a file inside the web application directory

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a file *TestFile.db* inside the web application directory. But I have been unsuccessful till now. I do not understand the reason.

*JSP snippet that attempts to create a file :*

```
        <% if(new FileMaker().makeFile()) {%>
        <h2>File Creation successful !</h2>
        <%} else {%>
            <h2>Unable to create a file !</h2>
            <%}%>
```

*Class that attempts to make a file:*

```
public class FileMaker {

private boolean success = false;

public boolean makeFile() {
    try {
        File f = new File("TestFile.db"); // CREATE A FILE
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(f);
        writer.println("This is a test statement on a test file");
        writer.close();
        success = true;
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return success;
    }
    return success;
}
}
```

The web-app named `App-1` structure looks like :

[image]

The above code doesn't create any exception and returns `true` but I do not see any file created. Why is that ? But if I change the statement like :

```
File f = new File("/App-1/TestFile.db");
```

I get a file not found exception. I do not understand the reason for this. Please explain both the cases. **How do I create a file inside the directory `App-1` ?**

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the proper path to filemaker.  You can do this by getting the proper path from the servlet context.

```
<%@page import="com.adtest.util.FileMaker"%>
<% if(new FileMaker().makeFile(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"))) {%>
    <h2>File Creation successful !</h2>
    <%} else {%>
        <h2>Unable to create a file !</h2>
        <%}%>
```

Next in your filemaker class add the path and only create if it does not extist.

```
public boolean makeFile(String path) {
    try {
        File f = new File(path+"\\TestFile.db"); // CREATE A FILE
        if(!f.exists())
            f.createNewFile();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(f);
        writer.println("This is a test statement on a test file");
        writer.close();
        success = true;
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return success;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: By default the path is the root of the project.

Comment: Yes the root by default is the directory where the process kicks off, but he is looking for the path of the web application directory.

Comment: Well, personally, I dont think that it is a good idea to create a file in the path of web-app dir. If you are going to manipulate with the files, why not to create a special folder for them and not to spend the nerves? :)

Comment: @Constantine create a special folder ? There are certain files I want to write during run time,just to stash some data. I choose creating these files within the web-app. It also ensures me , not to change the path if I test it on another pc

Comment: Exactly. You generate a constant path, for example static final tempFolder = "C:\myprojectapp", which could be created on any windows machine. Well, also you could make a workaround for linux. This is the way we did in our project some time ago.

Comment: @Constantine By default the current path inside a web app is undefined. It is most likely to be the bin directory of the app server. It certainly will not be the root of the web app, as Java doesn't provide a mechanism for the server to change it from web app to web app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug and use f.getAbsolutePath() to get the path of the file, where you create it. So, when you receive the path, you could modify it. Please update the question as more info comes.
You receive file not found, cause it seems, like it is not actually created. Do you actually call mkFile() command? :)

If the exists() returns false, make the following:

```
file.createNewFile("fileName");
//write some data to file.
```

createFileName() creates absolutely blank new file.

Comment: I want to create the file in the application context. I mean `/App-1/FileCreated`

Comment: and when I debug I get `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\bin\TestFile.db` from `getAbsPath`. But when I reach there I do not see any file

Comment: check the file with the .exists() method - if it returns false, then you have only the java object, but not actual file.

Comment: Well, this is weird. Let's try the Apache FileUtils. http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html - just add a jar to you project and make a FileUtils.touch() command. It is a force-make file method.

Comment: Oh, try to name it with some very specific name, run your program and search the operating system for it to make sure it creates and find the place of creation.

Comment: @saplingPro Open your IDE with admin priviliges. I see that you installed apache in your `C` drive.